# Access violation while trying to compute FFT (fast Fourier transform) of 2 images

Tags: c++, image-processing, access-violation, fftw

I am trying to take FFT of two raw images. But I am getting `unhandled exception (access violation)` - I could not figure out why. I am using fftw library.
First I am reading two images, then I calculate FFT. But before it starts calculating, it produces access violation error.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "fftw3.h"

#define Width 2280
#define Height 170

unsigned char im2[170*2280];
unsigned char im1[170*2280];
float image1[170*2280];
float image2[170*2280];

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    FILE* fp1, *fp2;

    //Read two images

    fp1 = fopen ("image1.raw" , "r");
    fread(im1, sizeof(unsigned char), Width* Height, fp1);

    fp2 = fopen ("image2.raw" , "r");
    fread(im2, sizeof(unsigned char), Width* Height, fp2);


    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp1);

    //Typecasting two images into float

    for (int i = 0; i < Width* Height; i++)
    {       
        image1[i]= (float)im1[i];
        image2[i] = (float)im2[i];

    }

    fftwf_plan fplan1, fplan2;
    fftwf_complex fft1[((Width/2)+1)*2];
    fftwf_complex fft2[((Width/2)+1)*2];

    fplan1 = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d(Height, Width, (float*)image1, fft1, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftwf_execute(fplan1);
    fftwf_destroy_plan(fplan1);

    fplan2 = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d(Height,Width, image2, (fftwf_complex*)fft2, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftwf_execute(fplan2);
    fftwf_destroy_plan(fplan2);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line gives you the access violation error?

Comment: @lightalchemist .raw files.  Files with only the pixel data are very common in image processing applications.

Comment: @Pace: The line  fftwf_execute(fplan1); gives me an error.

Answer (score 4):

`fft1` and `fft2` are only large enough to hold one output row - you need `Height` rows. You'll probably want to allocate them dynamically too, as they will most likely be too large for the stack once you have the correct size, e.g.

```
fftwf_complex *fft1 = new fftwf_complex[((Width/2)+1)*2*Height];
fftwf_complex *fft2 = new fftwf_complex[((Width/2)+1)*2*Height];
```

NB: don't forget to call `delete []` to free these later.